# Difference between shall and can

Tags: meaning

Yesterday I am going to a highway.
And I ask for a lady to drop her at home.
So in that situation I confused between two sentence.

So I wants to know what is the difference between following two term:

> 1. **Can** I drop you?
> 2. **Shall** I drop you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both "**Can I drop you?**" and "**Shall I drop you?**" sound fine. With respect to J.R. both "**drop somebody somewhere or at some place**" and "**drop somebody off somewhere or at some place**" are equally possible. They are quite common in informal English:

- Do you want me to drop you home?
- Do you want me to drop you off at home?

However, the "**drop somebody off**" idiom is more common. Depending on the kind of offer you make either "*shall*", "*can*", or "*may*" can be used in this situation.

There are several other ways you can ask that sort of thing:

- "**Need a lift home?**"
- "**Need a ride home?**"
- "**Shall I take you home?**"
- "**Shall I give you a ride home?**"
- "**Can I take you home?**"
- "**Can I offer you a lift home?**"
- "**May I offer to drop you home?**"
- "**May I offer to drive you home?**"

Comment: Aside from the fact that the intended verb was probably "drop off," the best form to convey an offer Is "May I drop you off."

Comment: I don't think ability applies in this informal conversation. [More here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/usage/can-or-may).

Answer (score 1):

You can use either one, although I think the version with "Can" sounds a bit more friendly and a bit less formal. In day-to-day conversation, using *shall* might sound a little stilted.

That being said, the phrasal verb you want to use is *drop off*, not *drop* (at least in American English). Asking if you can "drop someone" sounds like you want to lift them off the floor and then drop them.

So, the version I would recommend is:

> *Can I drop you off?*

Here's another way you might make the same offer:

> *Can I give you a ride home?*

Comment: Actually, both "**drop**" and "**drop off**" are possible. Of course I'm not a native speaker but I remember both usages from films and books.